# How to cut a string in two for creating a dataframe?

Tags: python, string

I have a list with firstname-lastname combinations, like:

```
['henry-dupuis', 'arthur-keynes', ...]
```

I would like to be able to split the string in two and create a dataframe:

```
df = 

     fullname   firstname   lastname

 henry-dupuis       henry     dupuis        
arthur-keynes      arthur     keynes
...
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
names = ['henry-dupuis', 'arthur-keynes'...]
splitted_names = [[elem] + elem.split('-')[:2] for elem in names]
df = pd.DataFrame(splitted_names, columns=["full-name", "fist-name", "last-name"])
```

Comment: What about hyphenated names?

Comment: @Sayse it is not possible to do that for some hyphenated names. eg. daniel-max-smith could be daniel-max as first name or max-smith as last name... Added the DataFrame part

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(names, columns=['FullName']) 
df['FirstName'] = df['FullName'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[0])
df['LastName'] = df['FullName'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[1])
```

Results:

```
        FullName FirstName LastName
0   henry-dupuis     henry   dupuis
1  arthur-keynes    arthur   keynes
```

Answer (score 0):

If the fullnames list you have '-' as a separator.

Then you can 
first run a loop over it and then split the elements of loop and create a dataframe out of it.

```
for element in fullnames:
    splitNames = element.split('-')
    firstName.append(splitNames[0])
    lastName.append(splitNames[1])

pd.DataFrame(firstName, columns=['firstName'])
pd.DataFrame(lastName, columns=['lastName'])
```

This will also create a pandas dataframe for the given firstName and lastName.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `str` functionalities of `pandas`, which are vectorised:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["henry-dupuis", "arthur-keynes", "james-arthur-conway"], columns=["fullname"])
df[["firstname", "lastname"]] = df.fullname.str.split("-", 1).apply(pd.Series)
print(df)
#               fullname firstname       lastname
# 0         henry-dupuis     henry         dupuis
# 1        arthur-keynes    arthur         keynes
# 2  james-arthur-conway     james  arthur-conway
```

This makes sure that the name is only split at the first `-`, in case there are more in the name. This might be wrong, but will at least work and be consistent. There is no way that any code will get this correctly everywhere. There are people called James-Arthur Conway and people called James Arthur-Conway. You should read [falsehoods programmers believe about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Anyways, if your data actually follows your given requirements, this code will work and be faster than any looping done in Python.